# Asp.net & C# email query?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm just wondering if someone could help me with a question, I would like if possible and not overly complicated to be able to click a button and when I do it will send an email to the person who submitted a change from the person logged in, this may sound confusing so is there anyway I can send an email to say a lecturer who wants something changed from the person who is logged in, I wouldn't want to manually type their email in each time because there could be many lecturers who send the changes for approval, I want to be able to send it to the person who in essence sent me the page for approval...

If anyone needs any further clarification to help me that would be great as im really struggling

Regards
RD

Comment: Show the code you've tried and where it has failed.

Comment: Thats the thing @B.Clay Shannon, I aint sure if this can be done or how to go about it so havent wrote anything regarding email sending, I just have a label saying changes made etc but how does the person who originally submitted changes suppose to know its been updated, can you send an alert?

Comment: If you can imagine it, you can do it; if you have the original submitter's email address, you can definitely do it. Google or Bing how - there are many examples here on StackOverflow and elsewhere.

Comment: Can you point me towards the best one? also there might be more than one lecturer so I wouldnt wanna have to change the email address in the c# everytime depending on who it is...

Comment: That's an exercise left to the OP; the lecturer's email would have to be something you could determine programmatically, certainly not hard-coded.

Comment: You got a good tutroial on how to do it, dosent even have to be email is there a method to send a label/ alert to another aspx page once a button is clicked so say the user logs back in they get that alert?

Comment: What did you find when you googled or binged for that?

Answer (score 1):

```
try
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.From = new MailAddress("e_mail_from");
        mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("lecturer_email"));
        mail.Subject = "Plan approval";
        mail.Body = "I request my plan approval";
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        client.Port = 587;
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("your_mail", "your_password");
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.Send(mail);
        mail.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //...
    }
    finally
    {
        //...
    }
```

Instead of *lecturer_email* you have to appoint lecturer's email (may be from session, DB or something else, it's up to you). *Your_mail* it is your mail's name without domain (test@test.ru -> test). And *your password* as plain text. So it would be better if you will create some email for this function.
I use with @gmail.com, it works excellent.
Namespaces:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
```

Hope it helps